# How to ensure that PHP SSE doesn't "disconnect"

Tags: php, server-sent-events

I have a small extra chatroom service running on my website, I'm using SSE to send chat updates to clients constantly, however, it seems the eventsource's message keeps triggering due to a disconnect and automatic reconnect, or at least that's what I've found out after scowering the internet for hours.

Here's my PHP

```
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$matchid = $_GET["curMatch"];

$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$filename = $root . "/pickup/chat/chatroom.txt";
$lastMod = NULL;

while(true){
    if(connection_status() != CONNECTION_NORMAL) {
        $conn->close();
        break;
    }

    clearstatcache();   

    $checker = filemtime($filename);
    if($checker != $lastMod){       
        $lastMod = $checker;
        echo "data: 1\n\n";
        ob_end_flush();
        flush();

        usleep(400);
    }   
}
```

Here's the jQuery

```
matchID = 1;
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {       
    var chatSource = new EventSource("/pickup/php/check-chat-sse.php?curMatch="+matchID);
    chatSource.onmessage = function(event) {
        var dt = new Date();
        var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();
        console.log("Chat Server responded: @" +time);          
        console.log(event.data);            

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/pickup/chat/"+matchID+".txt",
            datatype: 'text',
            success: function (response) {     
                $("#chat-content").html(response);
            }
        });
        if (hidden == true){
            $("#chat-toggle").addClass("newMessage");
        }
    }   
}
```

And Finally, the console logs

> Chat Server responded: @20:36:54
>   Chat Server responded: @20:37:24
>   Chat Server responded: @20:38:52

This causes the .newMessage class to be added every time the server reconnects thus making the users think there's a new message when there isn't. I'm running a more complex system on SSE as well with the same problem, so if I can get a solution this everything will be better.

So how do I ensure the user doesn't disconnect and reconnect without creating a reverse AJAX poll, as that's what most people suggest. Any suggestions or help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When the client browser disconnects, the php process will automatically be closed by Apache (I am assuming your are using Apache, as you didn't specify it). So the first four lines of your while() loop are not needed, and might be causing a problem. (But, if you do keep them, start logging the return value of `connection_status()` so you know why it is closing the connection.)

But, as your re-connects are happening every 30 seconds, my guess is that the PHP script is simply timing out. Try adding:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

at the very top of your script. (Alternatively, putting something like `set_time_limit(10)` inside your while loop is a more sophisticated approach, to catch genuine locked-up code.)

If it is not that, my guess would be you need to send some keep-alive messages. (My book, Data Push Apps with HTML5 SSE, goes into some detail on how to implement that.)

---

As an aside, have you considered sending the actual chat message in the SSE body, rather than just sending the "there is new data" message then requiring the client to do that extra request for them? It should be more efficient overall.

Comment: This seems to have done the trick, the reason I was handling the textfile's load browser side was to do some other load testing if the server had responded but the text file was still the same, now that this is fixed I'll let the server send the data. Would you mind explaining why set_time_limit(10) inside the while loop is more sophisticated. Up until a week ago I was using AJAX polling, so I'm quite new to SSE.  I'll be buying that book ASAP.

Comment: @RuanKruger `set_time_limit` is designed to catch program bugs such as infinite loops, or waiting for a lock that is never going to be released, etc. Most php scripts only need to run for a second, so the default 30s is a good buffer. Setting it to zero at the top of the script turns this safety-net feature off: by setting it inside the loop, you can get that safety net back. See http://php.net/set_time_limit for more.